# How to prevent blank lines in files or all code in one line and how to reformat them?

Tags: ftp, code-formatting

When I try to edit some code on remote server, that code contains blank lines or in some cases entire code is in one line. I know that this issue is related with FTP client transfer mode or file encoding or server type (unix or windows) .. or in what format files are saved.

In my working enviroment works all fine, but I have problems when I have to edit directly on some remote server (not allways). For my work I use notepad++, sublime text2 or netbeans.

One exmaple... In one company I occasionaly work for, they use Dreamwaver.  Dreamwaver connects directly on server and all files I edit with it are properly formated (no blank lines), but I don't like that editor, so I want to use my own. To connect to server I use WinSCP, but some files which I open have blank lines.

In one case I edited a file (WinSCP+Notepad++) and when I try to edit it next day all code were in one line, same problem was in Dreamwaver ... something went wrong day before .. or with file save or file upload.

So my questions are:

1. What is the possible cause of that and how to prevent it?
2. Why Dreamwaver doesn't have blank lines but notepad++ and sublimetext have them?
3. Is there an option in verious editor to ignore blank lines and hide them?
4. If blank lines are saved, is there a way to quickly remove them ? In notepadd++ you can choose edit / delete blank lines, but that often breaks some code.
5. If all code is in one line is there a way to reformat it with notepad++ or sublime text?

Comment: What language(s) is your code in question?

Comment: Mostly html,PHP,JS,CSS

Comment: You mentioned Dreamweaver, so look at the file in Dreamweaver, go to Modify -> Page Properties -> Title/Encoding and make sure BOM is not clicked.  Sometimes this adds line breaks.  Not sure if that helps, but it is all I've got.  That's why this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: I will check it out, but in DW usualy works fine. In notepad++ I allways save as UTF-8 without BOOM.

Answer (score 3):

in dreamwaver

- Click CTRL + F
- Select “Current document” in “Find in” (You can also select the folder if you have multiple files)
- Search in “Source code”
- Tick “Use regular expression”
- Type “[\r\n]{2,}” (without quotes) in “Find”
- Type “\n” (without quotes) in “Replace”
- Press “Replace All”

ref.http://www.brmecham.com/how-to-remove-blank-lines-in-dreamweaver/

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before, both in Dreamweaver and in Filezilla. As for preventing this problem, maybe this description of the source of the problem will help...
[Stop Filezilla from inserting blank lines](https://superuser.com/questions/1091022/stop-filezilla-from-inserting-blank-lines-in-text-files)

**Excerpt from the link above:**

> A Windows (CR+LF) text file was uploaded to a Unix-based FTP server in binary. If that file is downloaded in ASCII, the FTP server translates LF to CR+LF so the CR+LF line endings will be converted to CR+CR+LF. FileZilla on Windows does expect the file to already use CR+LF line encoding (per FTP specification), so no more translation is done. Depending on the text editor used, lines might be separated by an additional empty line now.

This solution seems to apply to Dreamweaver as well as Filezilla.

Try changing the options in Dreamweaver's [*Edit > Preferences > Code Format*] menu to find line break settings that work for you. 
[***Screenshot of my prefs.***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6fZq.jpg)
I had to try a couple options before it worked for me. Settings may vary depending on your web server too, although I'm certainly no expert.
I am running a Linux server and found settings that worked for that.

Also the "FTPExtensionMap.txt" is a config for binary/ascii ftp settings for different file types. Set the problem file types to binary. You can find that file in: *YOUR-USER-FOLDER\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS4\en_US\Configuration*. ***Exact path may vary depending on your version***... my version was obviously CS4.